# Load JQuery with Webpack4

Tags: jquery, webpack-4

I'm having a lot of problems trying to load JQuery with Webpack 4. When I check the console to see if JQuery is working I always get "jQuery is not defined" error message.

This is my webbpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const WebpackMd5Hash = require('webpack-md5-hash');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/scripts.js'),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname,'dist'),
        filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            //JQUERY
            {
                test: require.resolve('jquery'),
                use: [{
                  loader: 'expose-loader',
                  options: 'jQuery'
                },{
                  loader: 'expose-loader',
                  options: '$'
                }]
            },                
            //FONTS
            {
                test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'url-loader?limit=50000&name=fonts/[name].[ext]',
                    }
                ]
            },        
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: 'file-loader?limit=50000&name=fonts/[name].[ext]'}
                ]
            },            
            //JS
            {
                //Tipo de Archivo quiero reconocer
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                //Que Loader se encarga del tipo de extension de archivo
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets:['babel-preset-env']
                    }
                },
            },                                               
            //IMAGES
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|png|gif)$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        outputPath: 'img/',
                        name:'[name].[ext]', 
                    }
                }
            },                       
            //SASS
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ['style-loader', MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader']
            }           
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename:'css/style.min.[contenthash].css',
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin ({
            inject: false,
            hash: true,
            template: './src/index.html',
            filename: 'index.html'        
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'windows.jQuery': 'jquery',
        }),        
        new WebpackMd5Hash()   
    ]
}
```

As you can see I'm using expose loader and ProvidePlugin to try to accomplish this. So this is how I'm trying to import JQuery in my index.js:

```
import '../styles/style.scss';
import 'bootstrap';
import $ from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;
require.context("../img/", true, /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/);
require("expose-loader?$!jquery");
require("style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader!./font-awesome-sass-styles.loader!./font-awesome-sass.config.js");
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log('Hello World from JQuery');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone has the same problem in the future I could solve the problem using externals on my webpack.config.js, include this on your module. exports:

```
externals: {
    'jquery': 'jQuery'
},
```

When you use externals you are basically loading an external CDN, so you have to include it on your .html file (be sure to put it before your Webpack bundle js call or it won't work).

```
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"
    integrity="sha256-slogkvB1K3VOkzAI8QITxV3VzpOnkeNVsKvtkYLMjfk="
    crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>             
<script src="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks.main.entry %>"> 
<script>
```

Comment: This is one way of loading jQuery when you don't want to add jQuery to the bundle app but you import jQuery at runtime from index.html as shown above.

Comment: @Mac_W can you develop? I don't get why the downgrade. Thanks.